# Problems with setting Authorization in request headers from Java

Tags: java, apache, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am facing a problem where I am not able to set the "Authorization" Header. 
I am Able to set the rest of the headers but when I am using the particular Key I am not able to set any data. Please help.

```
URL myURL = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
String basicAuth = "Bearer 6f6b06fe-131e-314b-9ef8-42f2cbdcfc18";
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basicAuth");
myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
System.out.println(myURLConnection.getRequestProperties());
```

Hoping to hear soon. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know header is not setting

Comment: "I am not able to set any data". In what way?

Comment: replace this myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basicAuth");
with
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

Comment: Hi Ivar, The only instance i found the data is not taken up in header was when I used "Authorization". I even tried with "TEST" and that went in.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
myURLConnection.getRequestProperties()
```

does not list all headers.

By looking at the source of `HttpURLConnection` you notice `Authorization` is part of the headers excluded by `HttpURLConnection#getRequestProperties`.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/484e16c0a040/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java

This does not mean the header isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

I think You made a little mistake there, The value for the key Authorization must not be "basicAuth". So please replace the code with :

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Or try this :

```
 String basicAuth = "Bearer 6f6b06fe-131e-314b-9ef8-42f2cbdcfc18";
 String encodedAuth= Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes());
 myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedAuth);
```

Comment: Hi sForSujit,
Sorry for my mistake. But that also didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use URLConnection instead of HttpURLConnection

Answer (score -1):

Try with following code:

```
public void sendPost(String URL, String jsonData, String authUrl) throws Exception {
post = new HttpPost(URL);
// add header
post.setHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
if (!jsonData.isEmpty()) {
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonData, ContentType.create("application/json")));
}
client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
response = client.execute(post);
outputFile = new File("path of file");
fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
headers = response.getAllHeaders();
bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
for (Header header : headers) {
bw.write(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue() + "\n");
}

bw.write("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine());
bw.close();
}
```